# Roblox module script raycasting character even though character is in ignore list

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

So basically I was making a game, working on a combat tool and I was like "I might add a module script for raycasting so it will help later in the future!". So I did that but even though I put the character in ignore list it just raycasted the mask I put on my avatar. Here is the code:

```
local Raycast = {}

function Raycast.Cast(origin,dir,char)
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(origin, dir)
    local Params = RaycastParams.new()
    Params.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Exclude
    Params.FilterDescendantsInstances = {char}
    
    return raycastResult
end

return Raycast
```

Code I put in server script to raycast:

```
local result = Raycast.Cast(Character.PrimaryPart.Position,Character.PrimaryPart.CFrame.LookVector * 5,Character)

if result then
    print(result.Instance:GetFullName())
    local h = result.Instance.Parent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if h then
        h.Health -= 5
    end
end
```

I tried searching the web but nothing happened. I tried debugging and i couldnt find a problem.

I just want it to make the punch damage people if they touch the ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the Raycast method before you you create the RaycastParams object, and never actually pass the params object into the raycast call.

Your code should be something like:

```lua
local Raycast = {}

function Raycast.Cast(origin,dir,char)
    local Params = RaycastParams.new()
    Params.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Exclude
    Params.FilterDescendantsInstances = {char}
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(origin, dir, Params)
    
    return raycastResult
end

return Raycast
```